# this->getUser() returns null after validating Form

Tags: symfony

I'm building a form with customized option based on who is logged in.
The goal is to send an Invitation.

The kind of invitation you can send is determined by the getIsRefFrom() method (which is a method available for "User" objects.)

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Invitation;
use AppBundle\Form\InvitationType;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * Invitation controller.
 *
 * @Route("/private/invitation")
 */
class InvitationController extends Controller 
{
...
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {

        $invitation = new Invitation();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $userStruct = $user->getIsRefFrom();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\InvitationType', $invitation, array('userStruct' => $userStruct));         

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {     

            return new Response("<body>Hi</body>");

        }

        return $this->render('invitation/new.html.twig', array(
            'invitation' => $invitation,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

...
}
```

And here is my Form Type

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class InvitationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {       

        $builder
             //showing content of userStruct in a select field
            ->add('structure', EntityType::class,  array(
                    'label' => 'Structure:',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Structure',
                    'choices' => $options['userStruct'],
                    'placeholder' => 'Faites un choix',
                    'property' => 'libelle',
                    'mapped' => false
            ))


        ->add('destinataire');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Invitation',
            'userStruct' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Structure',
        ));
    }
}
```

The form displays OK, $this->getUser() returns my user, and the content of $user->getIsRefFrom() is correctly displayed in the form.

Moreover, the debug toolbar indicates that I am correctly logged in, as I fill in the form.

But when I <strike>validate</strike> submit the form, I get an error saying "Error: Call to a member function getIsRefFrom() on null " because obviously $this->getUser(); is now null.

The debug toolbar now indicates n/a (not logged in, no security context...)

It looks like the security context is not available at this point.

More info :

- I use be_simple_sso_auth (cas auth bundle).
- I have only one firewall (derriere_CAS), which covers the whole app, except login page which are enabled via ACL (see security.yml below)
- Authentication works fine.

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
  encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User: 
      algorithm: bcrypt

  role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]

  providers:
    users:
      entity: {class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: username } 



  firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        derriere_CAS:
            methods: GET
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            trusted_sso:
              manager: connect_sso 
              login_path: /private/login/
              check_path: /private/login/check
              login_action: false
              logout_action: false
              create_users: true
              created_users_roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ]
              failure_path: /erreur_identification
            logout:
              path: /logout_sso
              target: /

  access_control:
      - { path: ^/private/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
      - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I would appreciate any help or idea.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you try get user like this:  `$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I tried this already, but it is the same result : works in the first place, but not after validating form.

Comment: get user after form valid function

Comment: What means "when I validate the form", and when not?

Comment: By "Validate the form" I mean I click the 'submit' button.
I will try to change that in the question for more clarity

Answer (score -1):

So I finally found, if not an answer, at least a solution.

First of all, it seems that my logic here (calculating field values based on who is logged in the controller before sending it to my formbuilder) was not good.

The right way looks like this one : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data

But even then, my problem remained : my user was still not authenticated after submitting the form.

I ended up switching from BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle to the much more simple (ironically) [CasAuthBundle](https://github.com/PRayno/CasAuthBundle) and now everything works fine.

Thanks to those who tried to help me.

Comment: I have the same problem while using default symfony authorization.